Cannot see a list of control events in Visual Studio when using WinUI 3?
I’m currently working on a project using WinUI 3 in Visual Studio. In previous XAML-based frameworks like WPF, I could easily view a list of available events for a control (e.g., for a Button or a TextBox) using properties viewer, but I’m having trouble doing the same in WinUI 3.
In WinUI 3, is there a way to display a list of available events for a control or view all event names that could be used in EventTriggerBehavior?
For example, I want to see a list of possible events when setting EventName in an EventTriggerBehavior. In WPF, this was straightforward, but I can't seem to find a way to do it in WinUI 3.

I know that events can be found through documentation like this one:
WinUI Button Documentation,
but I find it quite inconvenient to look them up manually this way.
Any suggestions or solutions would be greatly appreciated!

C++ but similar problem - https://github.com/microsoft/microsoft-ui-xaml/issues/9163

There is no built-in way to do this but you can try the Tempo API Viewer. It's an app created by a member form the WinUI team. You can find it in the Microsoft Store.
Make sure to give it a STAR on the repo if you find the app useful.

